# command to get SHA1 of specific android project in windows

Tags: android

I am building video calling app in android using java language in which I am not able to get SHA-1 of specific project.It is only showing successful.I don't know why I am getting this issue.I have googled it a lot for same.but Now i have googled alot for command for finding SHA-1 using command

```
   keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\James\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

but the problem is how to get the SHA-1 of different projects because SHA-1 is different for different projects

I am uploading the image of given issue

[image: Problem is here]

screen for getting the sha using cmd command but The confusion is it belong to which projects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The SHA1 is the same for all projects you sign with a specific key. It is the combination of application package-name and signing that makes it unique per app.

Comment: can you please the give the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266964/android-video-calling-is-crashing/61267120?noredirect=1#comment108403560_61267120